Why did the Catholic Church ban Pascal's Pensées?
The Wikipedia page for Blaise Pascal's apologetic work Pensées says that the Catholic Church banned the book:

However as conflicting with the orthodoxy of the Catholic Church it has been forbidden to print or read by the Index Librorum Prohibitorum.

Source: Pensées - Wikipedia
Following Wikipedia's citations, Beacon for Freedom of Expression says the book was banned for religious reasons in 1789, but offers no other information. Following Beacon for Freedom of Expression's sources again brings you to FileRoom, but that mostly discusses one of Pascal's other works. FileRoom cites another source, Banned Books 387 B.C. to 1978 A.D., but it is a physical book that I don't have access to.
So why was Pensées banned? I've read articles online about the book, but they all praise it and don't mention anything about it being heretical. The only thing I could think of would be that the French Revolution was happening the same year it was banned, but I don't know how that would affect Pascal's works.

Pascal being associated with Jansenism is likely the culprit

Pascal poked fun and was scathing of the sophistry of the Jesuits, who would run rings around The Church's ethical standards on mortal and venial sins in order to justify any behaviour contrary to those standards. See online article by David Carlin on "Pascal and the Jesuits".  This probably has lot to do with the ban

@DDS But it doesn't say why. I don't think the Index itself gives explanations.

@Geremia Your point is well taken. I thought it might shed a little light and be helpful. Nevertheless, I shall delete my comment.

Probably for the same reason the Provincial Letters were placed on the Index.
Banned Books 387 B.C. to 1978 A.D., p. 23:


France: Lettres burned for being too free with the dignity of all secular authorities.

Pascal having become converted to the Jansenist teaching, the Lettres aroused a storm of controversy because of their anti-Jesuit flavor. Louis XIV ordered that the book “be torn up and burned at the ‘Croix du Tiroir’ at the hands of the High Executioner, fulfillment of which is to be certified to his Majesty within the week; and that meanwhile all printers, booksellers, vendors and others, of whatever rank or station, are explicitly prohibited from printing, selling, and distributing, and even from having in their possession the said book … under pain of public (exemplary) punishment.”



